# Trouble formatting fstream output with unknown strength and int length

Tags: c++, fstream

I am finishing up this c++ project I'm working on to take user input, calculate some values, and then write all of the data to a file. My problem is that I can't get the values to align correctly in the text file. I am using setw(), but this doesn't correctly align everything when the length of the user input is unknown. It just messes with the columns and makes them unaligned.

I've tried using the fixed operator, left align, right align, without much luck

Here's my code pertaining to writing to the file.

```
if (myfile.is_open()){
    myfile << "BASKETBALL COURTS AREA REPORT\n\n";
    myfile << "Court" << setw(25) << "Height" << setw(25) << "Width\n";
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            myfile << names[i] << setw(25) << " " << arr1[i] << setw(25) << arr2[i] <<"\n\n";
        }
      }
   myfile << "\nThe largest court is " << maxName << ": " << maximum << "\n" << "\n";
   myfile << "Total area covered by all courts: " << totalArea;
```

[I expect the columns to be completely aligned like in this picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuyKW.png)

[However the actual output looks more like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w81Ob.png)

If anyone could assist me with what to do I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The fist (most obvious) problem is that you're not setting the field width for the name of the court. By default, it's set to 0, so each name is printed in the minimum width necessary to display the whole name. Setting the other column widths doesn't accomplish much after that.

To set the width, you probably want to go through the items, find the widest one, then add on a few extra spaces to give a margin between columns.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct court { 
    std::string name;
    int height;
    int width;
};

int main() { 
    std::vector<court> courts { 
        { "Auburn park", 12, 16},
        { "Alabama", 14, 17},
        {"Wilsonville Stadium", 51, 123}
    };

    auto w = std::max_element(courts.begin(), courts.end(), [](court const &a, court const &b) { return a.name.length() < b.name.length(); })->name.length();

    for (auto const &c : courts) { 
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(w+5) << c.name 
                  << std::right << std::setw(5) << c.height
                  << std::setw(5) << c.width << "\n";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Auburn park                12   16
Alabama                    14   17
Wilsonville Stadium        51  123
```